# WiX can'f find my file : unable to load file, error LGHT0103

Tags: installation, wix

I am using WiX 3.5 and making an installer. I have used heat.exe to bundle all the files.
It produced a WiX file. I referred in main wxs files as componentgroup ref. When I build my installer, it throws the following exception.

> *light.exe : error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file
>   '..........\target\tmp-release\jboss-eap-5.0\jboss-as\server\all\deploy\httpha-invoker.sar\invoker.war\WEB-INF\classes\org\jboss\invocation\http\servlet\ReadOnlyAccessFilter.class'
>   with type ''.*

It is able load many files from this location, except the above file, even though the file is present.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I used the variable for the directory, `sys.SOURCEFILEDIR`, and it worked well.

Comment: can you add little more details and how to use it and where to place it..i am kind of new to wix

Comment: Please (pretty pretty pretty please).. could you elaborate on this answer?  I want it to work........but this is too short of an explanation.

Comment: How have you added the variable? Can you provide and example?

Answer (score 10):

Looks like you've hit the linker bug. As far as I can see, [it was already reported to the WiX team](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3171540&group_id=105970&atid=642714), and was scheduled for v4.0. The comment to the issue states the path is more than 255 characters, so a possible workaround for you is to re-work the files/folders layout to avoid the paths of that length.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The  answer of Ravz1234 works ! I used it with a environment variable e.g. `env.SourcePath`.

1) Set an environment variable to show on your Source Dir e.g. `C:\SourceDir`
2) On `heat.exe` add the argument `-var env.SourcePath` along with the other arguments

Comment: Tip: As answers come in, they can move around in the list. Ones with more popular results can bubble up to the top. Instead of saying "The above answer", it might be good to say "@JimBob's answer works" that way we can find it again when the order of answers shifts around.

Comment: I mean the answer of @Ravz1234. Also do not forget to restart command prompt to see the new variable.